# AVAudioPlayer sounds garbled on iPhone without headphones

Tags: avaudioplayer

I have 23 music files (10-20 seconds in length) that I want to play when the user selects them and presses the play button.  It works find on my iPad and on the simulators, with or without earphones.  But on the iPhone device without earphones, around 80% of the files sound garbled, the volume is low, and some are barely legible.  I can plug the earphones in, and they sound fine.  As soon as I unplug the earphones, the sounds are garbled again.

Since some of the files always play fine, I converted all the original mp3's that I was using into the AAC format with a sample rate of 44100.  But the same files play fine, while most are distorted when playing on the iphone device.

I've tried several settings for AVAudioSession category: playback, playAndRecord, ambient. I've tried storing the files in core data and using initWithData instead of initWithContentsOfURL.  Can anyone suggest what else I might try?  Or how I might get clues into why I'm having this problem?

Here is my code. There are 3 relevant files. The ViewController that has a button to play a selected music file, an AVPlaybackSoundController that has all the audio logic, and a Singleton that has an array with the filenames.

My ViewController creates an AVPlaybackSoundController through the Nib.

```
IBOutlet AVPlaybackSoundController *avPlaybackSoundController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVPlaybackSoundController *avPlaybackSoundController;

- (IBAction) playButtonPressed:(id)the_sender
{
    self.currentRhythmSampleIndex =  arc4random() % [[CommonData sharedInstance].rhythmSampleArray count];
    [self.avPlaybackSoundController playMusic:self.currentRhythmSampleIndex];
    self.playBtn.hidden=YES;
    self.pauseBtn.hidden=NO;
}
```

AVPlaybackSoundController.m

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    [self initAudioSession:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback];
    [self initMusicPlayer];
}
- (void) initAudioSession:(NSString *const)audioSessionCategory
{
    NSError* audio_session_error = nil;
    BOOL is_success = YES;
    is_success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:audioSessionCategory error:&audio_session_error];
    if(!is_success || audio_session_error){
        NSLog(@"Error setting Audio Session category: %@", [audio_session_error localizedDescription]);
    }
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
    audio_session_error = nil;
    is_success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&audio_session_error];
    if(!is_success || audio_session_error){
        NSLog(@"Error setting Audio Session active: %@", [audio_session_error
                                                      localizedDescription]);
    }
}
- (void) initMusicPlayer
{
    NSError* file_error = nil;
    NSURL* file_url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                      pathForResource:@"musicFile1" ofType:@"m4a"]
                                                        isDirectory:NO];    
    avMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file_url
                                                       error:&file_error];
    if(!file_url || file_error){
        NSLog(@"Error loading music file: %@", [file_error
                                            localizedDescription]);
    }
    self.avMusicPlayer.delegate = self;
    self.avMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0xFF; 
    [file_url release];
}    

-(void) playMusic:(NSUInteger)rhythmSampleIdx
{
    CommonData *glob = [CommonData sharedInstance];
    if (rhythmSampleIdx > [glob.rhythmSampleArray count])
        return; // bug if we hit here

    // if we were already playing it, just resume
    if ((self.avMusicPlayer) && (rhythmSampleIdx == self.currentRhythmSampleIndex)){
        [self.avMusicPlayer play];
    }
    else{ // re-init player with new rhythm
        if (self.avMusicPlayer){
            [self.avMusicPlayer stop];
            [self.avMusicPlayer setCurrentTime:0.0];
        }
        NSError* error = nil;
        RhythmSample *rhythmSample = [glob.rhythmSampleArray objectAtIndex:rhythmSampleIdx];
        NSString* rhythm_filename = [self getRhythmFileName:rhythmSampleIdx];
        NSURL* file_url = [[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                               pathForResource:rhythm_filename ofType:@"m4a"] isDirectory:NO]autorelease];
        self.avMusicPlayer = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file_url error:&error]autorelease];
        [self.avMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];  // shouldn't be needed since we are playing immediately
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"Error loading music file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }else{
            self.avMusicPlayer.delegate = self;
            self.avMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0xFF; // repeat infinitely
            self.currentRhythmSampleIndex = rhythmSampleIdx;
            [self.avMusicPlayer play];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to obtain the sound files from a different source.  The new sound files play fine.  I still have no theory as to why the old sound files would play with earphones, but not without them.  I really dislike finding solutions without understanding why they work.

Comment: what was your different source ?